# Ошибка в бэкенде из-за React-проектов

Tags: django, reactjs

Всем привет, изучаю программирование. Столкнулся с одной проблемой. В разных директориях находятся React-проекты, каждый из которых отвечает за определенную функцию. Мне необходимо, чтобы они одновременно работали, но когда я выполняю `npm start` для обеих, то возникает проблема, что бэкенд (`Django`), который связан с одним из реакт-проектов, не может сохранять информацию в БД (`MariaDB`) и выдает ошибку `"POST /django_registration/save_user_data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 222811`. Я поменял для другого реакт-проекта порт с 3000 на 3001, чтобы не было конфликтов, но это никак не повлияло на бэкенд. Ошибка возникает только, когда одновременно два реакт-проекта работают, как только отключаю второй на 3001 порту, бэкенд правильно обрабатывает запросы, сохранение и ошибок не возникает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это решить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Тебе 500-ую ошибку отдает - там проблема, бэку нет  дела до фронта - у тебя  просто ошибка